# What's this outlet of IAE V2500 for?

Tags: jet-engine, feature-identification, turbofan

Anybody knows what is this outlet for and why it is designed in such way?

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** On MD-90 didn't see such thingy

[image]

Comment: Why is the question dwon-voted? always I don't expect any up-vote but for down-vote it could be better to tell us the reason.

Comment: The picture of the MD-90 engine shows the exact same drain mast (see under the IAE logo)!?

Comment: @Bianfable Thank you for posting that nice answer. I'm not sure if it's the answer because the engine in that question is different but I guess you're right and that's the answer. Then I think it's better that an expert approves it or If you sure, please post your answer. lets not to close this question. this engine is different than that one.

Comment: @Bianfable Aren't the engine designers the designer of nacelles? Why are they different? Do the aircraft designers design the nacelles?

Comment: No the OEM designs the nacelles in close collaboration with the engine builder or builders.  Those types of protrusions are almost always fluid drains of some kind, or vents were fluid can also potentially exit, intended to keep fluid discharge in the freestream so it doesn't collect and flow along the skin.