# Why is the cockpit color of eastern aircrafts different than western's?

Tags: cockpit

Commonly, the cockpit of eastern aircraft have a MediumSpringGreen or PaleTurquoise color while the cockpit of western aircraft have a Black or Gray or SaddleBrown color. Is it kinda standard? e.g.

Tupolev Tu-142M3
[image: e cockpit]
Ilyushin IL-86
[image]
Boeing 747-84AF
[image]
Beechcraft B200GT Super King
[image]

Comment: Note that most common colour in western cockpits is probably gray, often with hint of the same turquoise as Russian manufacturers use, though never that saturated.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question was "Why are Soviet aircraft cockpits green", while this one is "why are Western and Soviet cockpits different colors?" If the Soviets found out that blue-green was the best color for cockpits, why didn't Western aircraft manufacturers adopt that color scheme as well?

Comment: @nick012000 This is not the first time for me. e.g. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83122/whats-this-outlet-of-iae-v2500-for

Comment: @nick012000 (and Roh) if you think this is not a duplicate vote to reopen or, if you can't vote to reopen, please start a discussion on meta

Comment: @Federico I can't vote to reopen, which is why I left a comment and flagged the question for moderator intervention.

Comment: @nick012000 opening a discussion on meta is better than asking for moderator intervention